# Adding text to a PDF which is signed/certified using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

I tried adding text to this PDF https://www.canada.ca/content/dam/ircc/migration/ircc/english/pdf/kits/forms/imm5476e.pdf using FPDF & FPDI, but unfortunately i received an error:

```
CrossReferenceException: This PDF document is encrypted and cannot be processed with FPDI.
```

This is my complete code:

```
<?php
$servpath = getcwd();

require_once('app/ThirdParty/fpdf/fpdf.php');
require_once('app/ThirdParty/fpdi/src/autoload.php');

use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;

try {
    // Initialize the FPDF object
    $pdf = new Fpdi();

    // Add a page from an existing PDF file
    $existingPdfPath = $servpath.'/files/project_files/7/imm5409e.pdf';
    $pdf->setSourceFile($existingPdfPath);
    $existingPdfPage = $pdf->importPage(1); // Import the first page from the existing PDF

    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($existingPdfPage);

    // Add text on the first page
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(255, 0, 0); // Red text color
    $pdf->SetXY(50, 50); // Set the position for the text
    $pdf->Cell(100, 10, 'IRCC First Name', 0, 1, 'C'); // Add the text

    // Output or save the modified PDF
    $outputPdfPath = $servpath.'/files/project_files/7/imm5409e-output.pdf';
    $pdf->Output($outputPdfPath, 'F');

    echo 'Text added successfully to the PDF.';
} catch (setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\CrossReference\CrossReferenceException $e) {
    echo 'CrossReferenceException: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch (setasign\Fpdi\PdfParser\PdfParserException $e) {
    echo 'PdfParserException: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'An error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

So i tought this would not be possible and then tried removing the protection in the PDF, so that the code can work. But i can't even remove the encryption in the PDF file. It says:

```
You cannot change security on this document because the document is signed or certified.
```

[image]

Is there any way that i can add text to this PDF file?

One hack i found was to open the PDF file in the browser and Print -> Save as PDF. The saved file works if i want to edit with PHP(FPDF & FPDI).

Is there a better way to do this, so that i can add text to this PDF dynamically?

Comment: is the file password protected?

Comment: Looks like the encryption has done its job then. Have you got the keys / password to reverse the encryption?

Comment: The PDF in question has a hybrid (XFA and AcroForm) form definition, and uses both encryption and a usage rights signature to take permissions and activate Acrobat features. "Print -> Save as PDF" removes both the usage rights signature and the encryption, and most likely also the XFA form definition. If for your use case the resulting PDF suffices, use it.

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth No, you can download the file from the link and open it.

Comment: @ADyson like i mentioned it is not password protected, but may be some signature encrypted.

Comment: @mlk nope, i tried that as well, it makes a txt file with the message "%%[ ProductName: Distiller ]%%
This PostScript file was created from an encrypted PDF file.
Redistilling encrypted PDF is not permitted.
%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%"

Comment: Well it would be pretty pointless to have such a signed file if it was as trivial as that to override it. So I imagine you'll struggle, and that this should be the expected outcome. If you're not the one who digitally signed the file, you shouldn't expect to be able to reverse it, except perhaps by foul means.

Comment: @ADyson if you read my question, i've mentioned the source, which is from canada.ca, so obviously it is not made by myself :) User: mkl gave an idea to use print to export a file that does not have such regulation. I do it by Print-> Microsoft print to PDF. This exports a PDF file without encryption. Now, only if can figure out how to do this PHP...

Comment: @Thowzif I know you're not the author, it was a rhetorical point

Comment: As for the print to PDF, I'm sure in your [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155188/adding-text-to-a-pdf-which-is-signed-certified-using-php?noredirect=1#comment136022036_77155188) you said that hadn't worked?

Comment: @ADyson yes 'Print -> Adobe PDF/Save as PDF' does not work, but 'Print -> Microsoft print to PDF' does the trick and i was able to add text to the pdf using FPDF. The issue now is that the pdf has lost all its form fields and hence it cant be edited :(

Comment: If you modify it, the signature won't verify. This is the basic idea of a signature, to reveal modification of the signed content...

Comment: @HonkderHase Yes i highly doubt that as well, but i also believe that all they need is the filled PDF form, with the right information. I say this because some people print this on paper, fill them, scan as PDF and send it back.

Comment: Instead of trying to stamp text onto the page, can you instead just fill out the form? pdftk is a great utility and there are [PHP wrappers](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk) for it

Comment: @ChrisHaas but like mentioned above, Is it even possible to add text to form fields in a certified/encrypted file(not password protected)?

Comment: When I inspect the document with Adobe Acrobat, I can see that the security settings allow "Filling of form fields". Whether any specific tool can do it, I can't say, except to say that I have definitely done it in the past.

Comment: @ChrisHaas this would be a game changer and can save me a lot of time. Would you be kind enought to show me an example of how you did it please?

Comment: I don't have time at this moment, but you can check the documentation for a library such as https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk#fill-form

Comment: @ChrisHaas Much appreciated!